# Scikit Logistic Regression summary output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

is there a way to have a similar, nice output for the scikit logistic regression models as in statsmodels? With all the p-values, std. errors etc. in one table?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Do you know by chance, how to calculate the p-values or at least the std. errors with the information I could get from the scikit logistic regression by hand?

Comment: You'd really just have to roll your own output function/class. This is one of the biggest drawback of scikit, I think, but it makes sense that they don't have a summary function for *just* linear models. It wouldn't be completely generalizable, like the rest of scitkit is.

Comment: @TheDude, See code below - it calculates standard errors from multiple scikit logistic regression models.

Answer (score 1):

As you and others have pointed out, this is a limitation of scikit learn. Before discussing below a scikit  approach for your question,  the “best” option is to use statsmodels as follows:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm 
smlog = sm.Logit(y,sm.add_constant(X)).fit()
smlog.summary()
```

X represents your input features/predictors matrix and y represents the outcome variable. Statsmodels works well if X lacks highly correlated features, lacks low variance features, feature(s) don’t generate “perfect/quasi-perfect separation”, and any categorical features are reduced to “n-1” levels i.e., dummy-coded (and not “n” levels i.e., one-hot encoded as described here: [dummy variable trap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224051/one-hot-vs-dummy-encoding-in-scikit-learn)).

However, if above isn't feasible/practical, one scikit approach is coded below for fairly equivalent results - in terms of feature coefficients/odds with their standard errors and 95%CI estimates. Essentially, the code generates these results from distinct logistic regression scikit models trained against distinct test-train splits of your data. Again, make sure categorical features are dummy coded to n-1 levels (or your scikit coefficients will be incorrect for categorical features).

```
 #Instantiate logistic regression model with regularization turned OFF
log_nr = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = True, penalty 
= "none")

##Generate 5 distinct random numbers - as random seeds for 5 test-train splits
import random
randomlist = random.sample(range(1, 10000), 5)

##Create features column 
coeff_table = pd.DataFrame(X.columns, columns=["features"])

##Assemble coefficients over logistic regression models on 5 random data splits
#iterate over random states while keeping track of `i`
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
for i, state in enumerate(randomlist):
    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y,   stratify=y, 
    test_size=0.3, random_state=state) #5 test-train splits
    log_nr.fit(train_x, train_y) #fit logistic model 
    coeff_table[f"coefficients_{i+1}"] = np.transpose(log_nr.coef_) 

##Calculate mean and std error for model coefficients (from 5 models above)
coeff_table["mean_coeff"] = coeff_table.mean(axis=1)
coeff_table["se_coeff"] = coeff_table.iloc[:, 1:6].sem(axis=1)    

#Calculate 95% CI intervals for feature coefficients
coeff_table["95ci_se_coeff"] = 1.96*coeff_table["se_coeff"]
coeff_table["coeff_95ci_LL"] = coeff_table["mean_coeff"] - 
coeff_table["95ci_se_coeff"]
coeff_table["coeff_95ci_UL"] = coeff_table["mean_coeff"] + 
coeff_table["95ci_se_coeff"]
```

Finally, (optionally) convert coefficients to odds by exponentiating  as follows. Odds ratios are my favorite output from logistic regression and these are appended to your dataframe using code below.

```
#Calculate odds ratios and 95% CI (LL = lower limit, UL = upper limit) intervals for each feature
coeff_table["odds_mean"] = np.exp(coeff_table["mean_coeff"])
coeff_table["95ci_odds_LL"] = np.exp(coeff_table["coeff_95ci_LL"])
coeff_table["95ci_odds_UL"] = np.exp(coeff_table["coeff_95ci_UL"])
```

This answer builds upon on a somewhat related reply by @pciunkiewicz available here : [Collate model coefficients across multiple test-train splits from sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273013/collate-model-coefficients-across-multiple-test-train-splits-from-sklearn)