# Collate model coefficients across multiple test-train splits from sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I would like to combine the model/feature coefficients from multiple (random) test-train splits into a single dataframe in python.

Currently, my approach this is to generate model coefficients for each test-train split one at a time and then combining them at the end of the code.

While this works, this is excessively verbose and not feasible to extend to very large number of test-train splits.

Can somebody simplify my approach with a simple for loop perhaps?  My inelegant, excessively verbose, code follows below:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


####Instantiate logistic regression objects
log = LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced', random_state = 1)

#### import some data 
iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data[:100, :], columns = ["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width"])
y = iris.target[:100,]

#####test_train split #1
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X,y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, random_state=11)
log.fit(train_x, train_y) #fit final model 

pred_y = log.predict(test_x) #store final model predictions 
probs_y = log.predict_proba(test_x) #final model class probabilities

coeff_final1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(log.coef_))], axis = 1)
coeff_final1.columns=("features", "coefficients_1")

######test_train split #2
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X,y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, random_state=444)
log.fit(train_x, train_y) #fit final model 

pred_y = log.predict(test_x) #store final model predictions 
probs_y = log.predict_proba(test_x) #final model class probabilities

coeff_final2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(log.coef_))], axis = 1)
coeff_final2.columns=("features", "coefficients_2")

#####test_train split #3
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X,y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, random_state=21)
log.fit(train_x, train_y) #fit final model 

pred_y = log.predict(test_x) #store final model predictions 
probs_y = log.predict_proba(test_x) #final model class probabilities

coeff_final3 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(log.coef_))], axis = 1)
coeff_final3.columns=("features", "coefficients_3")

#####test_train split #4
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X,y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, random_state=109)
log.fit(train_x, train_y) #fit final model 

pred_y = log.predict(test_x) #store final model predictions 
probs_y = log.predict_proba(test_x) #final model class probabilities

coeff_final4 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(log.coef_))], axis = 1)
coeff_final4.columns=("features", "coefficients_4")

#####test_train split #5
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X,y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1900)
log.fit(train_x, train_y) #fit final model 

pred_y = log.predict(test_x) #store final model predictions 
probs_y = log.predict_proba(test_x) #final model class probabilities

coeff_final5 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.columns),pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(log.coef_))], axis = 1)
coeff_final5.columns=("features", "coefficients_5")

#######Append features/coefficients & odds ratios across 5 test-train splits

#append all coefficients into a single dataframe
coeff_table = pd.concat([coeff_final1, coeff_final2["coefficients_2"], coeff_final3["coefficients_3"],coeff_final4["coefficients_4"], coeff_final5["coefficients_5"] ], axis = 1)

#append mean and std error for each coefficient
coeff_table["mean_coeff"] = coeff_table.mean(axis = 1)

coeff_table["se_coeff"] = coeff_table[["features", "coefficients_1", "coefficients_2", "coefficients_3", "coefficients_4", "coefficients_5"]].sem(axis=1)
```

The final table looks as follows:

[image]

Can somebody show me how to generate the above table without writing all the lines of code above from test-train splits # 2 to test-train splits #5?

Comment: There's a number of steps to this. Have you taken a stab at it? What part is tripping you up? Generally, you can use a for loop, and then insert the results into a dataframe within the loop. If parameters like test_size or random_state vary for each element, you could set up a dictionary or list and access the elements as you iterate. Any of that specifically that you're struggling with?

Comment: The test size will be same throughout, but random state will vary. I was having trouble with appending the coefficients for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can do this with a for loop:

```py
# start by creating the first features column
coeff_table = pd.DataFrame(X.columns, columns=["features"])

# iterate over random states while keeping track of `i`
for i, state in enumerate([11, 444, 21, 109, 1900]):
    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(
        X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.3, random_state=state)
    log.fit(train_x, train_y) #fit final model 

    coeff_table[f"coefficients_{i+1}"] = np.transpose(log.coef_)
```

Note that we are dropping the `predict` and `predict_proba` calls in this loop since those values are being thrown away (overwritten each time in your code), however you can add them back using similar logic in the loop to create new columns in your table.

Comment: Your code takes a bit of time to fully follow but worked beautifully! If you could add an explanation of the enumerate part within the for loop that would be much appreciated. Thank you as well for pointing out and removing the extraneous predict/predict_proba code.

Comment: Check out [this page](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) which summarizes it really well and provides examples :)

Comment: How to retrieve the X matrix values and y values within each test/train dataset generated for each iteration?

Comment: @veg2020 You could assign them to a new dictionary, taking advantage of the enumeration you're doing, and then retrieve them from that new dict.